# Can I selectively disable individual fluentd plugins without removing them from the configuration file?

Tags: fluentd

I have a docker-compose setup with containers logging into fluentd.  To support different demo environments, I have events being output to multiple destinations (ElasticSearch, Splunk, Syslog, etc.)

I would like to maintain a single configuration file, but disable output plugins that are not needed.  If I have 4 potential output destinations, I would have to maintain 10 different configuration files to support all the different possible combinations.

I know that plugins can use environment variables for configuration parameters, which would be ideal.  However, I don't see that there is a common 'enabled' or 'disable' parameter in the underlying plugin architecture.

Is there any way to disable a plugin externally?  Or will I have to dynamically build my configuration file from an external script?

Comment: Not sure if something like that exists for the plugins that are part of the fluentd's core. The alternative that you have already mentioned is the way to go. You can divide your configuration into multiple files e.g. https://github.com/CloudWebManage/cwm-worker-logger/tree/main/config and then use the environment variable in entrypoint script e.g. https://github.com/CloudWebManage/cwm-worker-logger/blob/main/entrypoint.sh#L12-L21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this with environment variables by specifying the plugin type externally:

```
<label @SPLUNK>
  <match docker.**>
    @type "#{ENV['FLUENTD_SPLUNK_PLUGIN']}"
    ...
```

Externally, I either set FLUENTD_SPLUNK_PLUGIN=splunk_hec or FLUENTD_SPLUNK_PLUGIN=null based on whether the output should be enabled.  So far the only downside to this is a bunch of warnings from the 'null' output plugin for the parameters that are defined in the config block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LABELS and ENV vars to redirect to the appropriate output group.
As an example

```
# match all events
<match **>
  @type relabel
  @label @OUTPUT
</match>


<label @OUTPUT>
  #Add service_name to all events 
  <filter **>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
      service_name ${tag}
    </record>
  </filter>

  <match **>
    @type relabel
    @label "@#{ENV['OUTPUT_LABEL']}"
  </match>
</label>


<label @OUTPUTPROD>

  #match all events
  <match **>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
    <store>
      @type newrelic
      license_key "#{ENV['STORE_API_KEY']}"
      base_uri "#{ENV['STORE_ENDPOINT']}"
    </store>
  </match>
</label>

<label @OUTPUTDEV>

  #match all events
  <match **>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
  </match>
</label>
```